# Changing color in grouped barplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

This is my matrix

```
n =

   46.4000   51.8000
   44.8000   44.9000
   67.2000   85.0000
   54.4000   60.3000
   43.2000   57.0000
   51.2000   68.0000
   75.2000   76.0000
   44.8000   51.3000
   67.2000   72.2000
   70.4000   71.2000
```

If I plot it like bar(n, 'grouped') it shows

[image: BarPlot]

I want to change the default colors instead of blue red I want green and yellow

I tried like this way bar(n, 'grouped','g','y') But it is showing
[image: secondplot]

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `'FaceColor'` property of the handles to the objects:

```
n=[46.4000   51.8000
   44.8000   44.9000
   67.2000   85.0000
   54.4000   60.3000
   43.2000   57.0000
   51.2000   68.0000
   75.2000   76.0000
   44.8000   51.3000
   67.2000   72.2000
   70.4000   71.2000];
bar_handle = bar(n,'grouped');
set(bar_handle(1),'FaceColor',[0,1,0])
set(bar_handle(2),'FaceColor',[1,1,0])
```

The documentation explains how to set the colors [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#namevaluepairarguments).

Answer (score 3):

For matlab2014b and higher

Using `set` doesn't seem to work anymore since matlab2014b and gives the Message  (`Error using subsindex: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.`).

Try it directly with the handle:

```
n=[46.4000   51.8000
44.8000   44.9000
67.2000   85.0000
54.4000   60.3000
43.2000   57.0000
51.2000   68.0000
75.2000   76.0000
44.8000   51.3000
67.2000   72.2000
70.4000   71.2000];

bar_handle = bar(n,'grouped');
bar_handle(1).FaceColor = 'r'
bar_handle(2).FaceColor = 'b'
```

Comment: This behaviour is reflective of versions from R2014b and higher.  You should probably make a small note that talks about this so that you don't confuse people who have versions from R2014a or less as those versions still require using `set` to change plot properties.

Comment: With my R2015b it was necessary to add `bar_handle(1).EdgeColor = 'r';
bar_handle(2).EdgeColor = 'b'` after the FaceColor.